# What is the optimal number of times one should meet one's PhD. advisor?

Tags: graduate-school, advisor

I see sad students who meet may be once in a month and they complaint of not having enough progress. I have seen systems where the prof meets almost every few hours on weekdays and the prof is basically continuously working with the students. I see students who meet every 2-3 days or every week.

So what is the "right" frequency if at all?
What is the good frequency?

Once the weekly(instant) gratification of getting full scores on the course homework is removed it is quite a challenge to keep a gauge of whether one has made any progress during the week. How does one measure progress during the week during one's PhD?

Comment: The last paragraph asks an entirely different question - I suggest that it be made into a separate question on its own!

Comment: Do you only consider one-on-one meetings?  Many groups have weekly group meetings that may include a part where everyone briefly describes what they've done in the past week; then the supervisor gets an update from all group members, including PhD students.

Answer (score 19):

To expand on Peter's great answer, I'd also like to throw out the idea that the "ideal" frequency varies not only case-by-case, but also may change *during the course of one's graduate education*.

A beginning graduate student will very likely need much more supervision than a student in the middle of her program. Similarly, the student who is finishing up may need more frequent contact, but only because changes are probably happening at a very rapid pace, and it's important to make sure deadlines are completed on time.

From my own experience, I started out meeting weekly with my advisors; after about a year or so, the meetings became every two weeks, but then toward the end became weekly again (for the last two or so months before the defense).

Within my current group, I use a similar scheme: new students have weekly meetings, while older students (and the postdocs) meet every other week, or as needed. (Some of my students get along quite fine meeting with me only once every three to four weeks, and I'm fine with that, because they are independent enough not to need more "face-to-face" time.)

The important thing, I think, is that the PhD student should know that the time is *available*, if she needs it. However, it's also been my belief that it's when the student *doesn't* want to meet that it's actually most important to do so. This usually means that something's not quite right—and that's when intervention can make the most difference!

Answer (score 15):

The "right" frequency is probably "enough". Whereas this may seem like a joke, it is not. The frequency with which you need to meet your advisor will primarily depend on you, your advisor and your project (work conditions). If someone complains about not meeting enough, it can be because of two things, either they do indeed not meet enough or maybe the student is not independent enough. It is important to be self-critical on both sides. The problem is, in other words, that each student-advisor relationship is different and enough may not be what either the student or the professor thinks is enough. A minimum should from my perspective include meetings to iron out the really difficult points in the work and to provide feedback on thesis revisions, prepare for lab or field work or the equivalent and to simply touch base on a regular basis (perhaps monthly). If there is a social environment where you meet, that is fine but not necessary.

I personally had a weekly "show-and-tell" with the research group my advisor ran. These meetings were awful and more stressful than anything else. I could have done better without them. I probably met and discussed my thesis once per month on average, certainly more when writing up. I doubt my story is neither unique  nor typical.

Comment: The last sentence has two negatives. Did you mean " I doubt my story is either unique or typical."