# Advisor-student meeting patterns in very high-end theoretical research

Tags: phd, advisor, time-management

*This is related to my [previous question: “What is the optimal number of times one should meet one's PhD. advisor?”](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9136/what-is-the-optimal-number-of-times-one-should-meet-ones-phd-advisor)*

- I want to know of specific details of advisor-student meetings, frequencies, patterns in very high-end theoretical subjects like say algebraic geometry or string theory. Like if anyone knows of accounts of how it goes for say students of Vafa or Witten or Nima or Seiberg or Xi Yin or Kiran Kedlaya or Mattihas Zaldarriagga or Bjorn Poonen and such.
- In such subjects how does one keep oneself motivated since publications aren't so regular probably and progress is possibly very "slow"?

I mean, in such subjects how does one measure progress on a daily/weekly basis to understand if things are going well? (once the instant gratification of homework scores are removed, in full time research mode how is progress measured on weekly scales?)

Comment: To what extent is work in these areas driven by the reading - contemplation - discussion cycle that seems to be common in the theory driven humanities?

Comment: Tough to say.  I intersect with CS/Engr/Psyc, but only a little with pure math/probability theory.  All of my fields I touch tend to do quite a bit of meetings to hash out big ideas, theory, or implementation details (e.g., weekly or biweekly at least).  I didn't see the read-contemplate phase as being distinct: you'd read as you went along and shared as was relevant or felt people should be informed.  More like a read-discuss-contemplate cycle.

Comment: I'm also not sure how "slow" between publications matters.  Engineering can be VERY slow between pubs sometimes (imagine having to prove it, then build it, then test it).  The issue is the measurement of progress.  Proofs are like trying to move a Rubics cube from one state to another, in my opinion.  You don't know for sure if there's a way to transform it into the new state until you show it.  A set of transformations that might seem to be leading there might run into a dead end (no way to justify a certain leap).  Design is often much simpler, as it's modular so you see forward progress.

Answer (score 7):

> Once the instant gratification of homework scores are removed, in full time research mode how is progress measured on weekly scales?

There are three ways to make progress.

1. The big picture: identifying problems to work on, conjectures and consequences, outlining potential proof techniques.
2. The little picture: examples, computations, completing the proofs of individual lemmas.
3. Background reading/study: figuring out what you need to know and learning it.

In any given week it's reasonable to expect some progress on at least one of these.  It might not be dramatic or important progress, but at least you can work out some more details for a key example or read another chapter in a book you need to get through.  You can also refine your ideas, for example by identifying obstacles or additional ideas for a proof outline.  This sort of progress is on a much smaller scale than a research paper, but it lets you measure your progress and ensure your research is on track.

It might occasionally happen early in grad school that you spend a week feeling bewildered and completely unsure of what to do, but at that point your advisor should intervene and help you find something productive.

> I want to know of specific details of advisor-student meetings, frequencies, patterns in very high-end theoretical subjects like say algebraic geometry or string theory.

I don't think this would be as illuminating you as hope.  There's not a lot to learn from these patterns, and what you do learn could even be misleading: one advisor's approach might be a poor fit for another advisor, and a famous researcher may or may not be a wonderful advisor.

However, if you are looking for examples, [Kiran Kedlaya](http://math.ucsd.edu/~kedlaya/notes_students.shtml) and [Ravi Vakil](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/potentialstudents.html) have descriptions on the web of their advising styles.  (As one would expect, they differ in some respects, for example on meeting schedules.)  Some of the details are probably relevant only if you are considering them as possible advisors, but both pages contain some excellent advice that is more broadly applicable.

Comment: +1 for the links to Kedlaya's and Vakil's descriptions of their advising styles -- very informative!

Comment: _It might occasionally happen early in grad school that you spend a week feeling bewildered and completely unsure of what to do_ — The phrase "early in grad school" is redundant here.  **If you're lucky,** you'll have these confused weeks throughout your entire career.

Comment: @JeffE: I guess I meant "completely unsure of what to do" in the sense of "unable to figure out anything to try".  I agree that every research career will be full of confused weeks, but once one has some experience there are always things to try.  (They might not help, but at the very least you can try generic strategies like "try computing another example and looking for patterns" or "look for a simpler, related question to work on first".)

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: Yep, I know what you meant.  I stand by my comment.  If you're lucky, you'll periodically run into problems where none of the obvious strategies provide any insight.  (I'm assuming here that "give up" is _not_ one of the obvious strategies.)

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician But none of these 3 points you mentioned necessarily lead to publications and at the end of the day its the only thing about one's PhD that is ever going to count! One needs kind of 10 good publications in PhD these days to survive well in academia. (and that has to happen in kind of 3 years) What one did in a week is really not worth anything unless that converts into something publishable! I am not sure how to keep oneself motivated during the PhD - depressions of career uncertainties set in whenever something "fails".

Comment: @user6818: I think you are more worried than you need to be.  You definitely don't need to write 10 papers in grad school to get a good job in algebraic geometry (the number of people who can do this each year is tiny).  One good paper is enough to get a research postdoc, and if you can write several good papers you are doing great.  You are right that the three things I mention aren't automatically sufficient to write papers, but they are necessary, so there's no way to avoid this.  It's important to keep writing papers in the back of your mind, but not to let it take over your life.

Comment: The issue is that to have a strong research career, you need to do things that aren't focused on short-term paper writing.  You need to explore ideas that might fail.  You need to learn things just because they're interesting (if you haven't already studied something before you need it, you may not even recognize where it could be applied).  You need to play with ideas and see where they lead you.  You're right that it's important to write papers, but if you do only things that contribute directly to writing papers now, it will limit what you can achieve in your research.

Comment: So it's important to be productive, but productivity is broader than just what contributes to a paper this month or even this year.

Comment: @Anonymous Mathematician (1) I don't think my 10 papers in PhD. is a random number - look at the PhD. track record of the post-docs in the major US universities in areas like condensed matter theory, cosmology or string theory (2) This reading widely is a very uncommon advice - since the best PhD students (who are now post-docs in the major US universities) I have known would serious warn AGAINST it - all of them claim that the only way to succeed professionally is to focus only at the paper one is working on at hand

Comment: - they say that they never studied any text book which is even slightly outside their project.

Comment: @user6818: I don't know what sort of publication track record is typical in physics grad school (and it probably differs a lot from mathematics), but ten publications is an extremely large number for an algebraic geometry grad student.  As for reading, you certainly don't want to do so much of this that it distracts you from research, but never learning anything not directly related to a current project seems too far in the opposite direction.  In any case, I'd recommend doing what your advisor and other successful people in your research area advise.

Comment: @user6818: "the best PhD students"  I think the end of that phrase is the operative word.  Being the best PhD student does not reflect being the best researcher long-term.  Ultimately, successful people on the tenure track run labs and manage people.  This involves having to keep an eye on many pots, not just focusing on one paper.  Admittedly, you want to build a specialty "niche" that you're known for (e.g., "World's leading expert in the dynamics of cookie dough").  But someday, that cookie might crumble (e.g., funding dries up) and you'll be glad to have some breadth.

Comment: @Namey: Again, field dependent.  In pure mathematics, there's no such thing as a "lab" to run, and the maximum extent to which one "manages people" is usually advising grad students - and at many places, one does not take on grad students until after tenure.